# Wisiwyg - with only 2 lines we can INSERT image but now, how resize image into element?

Tags: image, insert, resize

I need one wysiwyg absolutely basic.

Then because I not found in GOOGLE, I am trying create one.

I write this elemental lines:

```
<a href="#" onclick="w2('n');return false;">Bold</a> <a href="#" onclick="w2('i');return false;">Img</a>
<hr /><div contenteditable="true" id="html">Some text in DIV<br />Some text in DIV<br /></div>
<br /><textarea name="codigo" id="tags_html" cols="33" rows="9"></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
function w2(a){
    document.getElementById('html').focus();
    if(a == 'n')document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
    if(a == 'i')document.execCommand('InsertImage', false, 'https://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml20.png');
    document.getElementById('tags_html').value = document.getElementById('html').innerHTML;
    }
/*]]>*/</script>
```

and yes, this run correctly.

But: I need change SIZE keeping the aspect ratio.

is clear I no want use libraries or JQUERY.

Insert is very short code,
but... change size keeping ratio is very difficult/large ?

Answer (score 0):

the unique "trick" is the 3 instructions CSS:

```
img {
    resize:both;
    object-fit:cover;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

and here code complet:

```
<style type="text/css">img{resize:both;object-fit:cover;
overflow:hidden;
}#codigohtml{display:table-block;border:3px double #000;padding:1em;width:90%;height:13em;margin:0 auto;}
textarea{display:none;}</style>
<form action="http://sinelco.org/index2.php" target="_blank" onsubmit="w2(0);">
<div><a href="#" onclick="w2('n');return false;">Bold</a> <a href="#" onclick="w2('i');return false;">Img</a><hr /><p contenteditable="true" id="codigohtml"></p></div>
<br /><input type="submit" /><input type="hidden" name="codigohtml" id="pruebahtml" /></form>
<p>More lines...</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
    function w2(a){
        document.getElementById('codigohtml').focus();
        if(a == 'n')document.execCommand('bold', false, null);
        if(a == 'i')document.execCommand('InsertImage', false, 'https://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml20.png');
        if(a == 0)document.getElementById('pruebahtml').value = document.getElementById('codigohtml').innerHTML;
        }
    /*]]>*/</script>
```